# How to do nested queries in neo4j

Tags: neo4j

Can't figure out how to do this in a good way in neo4j, so please help me.

I have Three types of objects: Person, Object, Opinion.
I want to get a list of the latest opinions, the person who had the opinion, the object. This I can do, it's not difficult. 
My problem starts when I want to get the people that has opinions about the same objects in the same query.

This is the result I would like to have:

1. Person: Berit, Object: cerials, Opinion: good

   - Person: Arne, Object: cerials, Opinion: good
   - Person: Albert, Object: cerials, Opinion: bad
2. Person: Axel, cookbooks, awesome

   - Person: Arne, Object: cookbooks, Opinion: unnecessary
   - Person: Tove, Object: cookbooks, Opinion: bad
   - Person: Berit, Object: cookbooks, Opinion: bad

... And so on

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't describe your relationship types, so I'll just make them up.  Here is how you might start:

```
MATCH (target:Person)-[:HAS_OPINION]->(target_opinion:Opinion)-[:ON]->(object:Object)<-[:ON]-(other_opinion:Opinion)<-[:HAS_OPINION]-(other_person:Person)
WHERE target.id = {target_id}
```

The target could be based on id/name/whatever...

You could return the data in a couple of ways.  It could be a denormalized result:

```
MATCH (target:Person)-[:HAS_OPINION]->(target_opinion:Opinion)-[:ON]->(object:Object)<-[:ON]-(other_opinion:Opinion)<-[:HAS_OPINION]-(other_person:Person)
WHERE target.id = {target_id}
RETURN target, target_opinion, object, other_opinion, other_person
```

Or you could return one target per row and collect all of the others up into an array of objects:

```
MATCH (target:Person)-[:HAS_OPINION]->(target_opinion:Opinion)-[:ON]->(object:Object)<-[:ON]-(other_opinion:Opinion)<-[:HAS_OPINION]-(other_person:Person)
WHERE target.id = {target_id}
RETURN
  target,
  target_opinion,
  object,
  collect({opinion: other_opinion, person: other_person}) AS others
```

Comment: Thank you! This was what I was looking for.