# How to chain queries in Neo4j using NodeJS driver while merging some data in a new property?

Tags: javascript, node.js, neo4j

I have a list of tagged elements in Javascript object format that I'm writing an import function for in a NodeJS project. There might be duplicates of these elements in the list since the list is a combination of lists from different sources.

**Example list (this is the contents of test.json):**

```
[
    //0 - first time this element appears on the list
    {
        name       : "Name 1",
        identifier : "string0001",
        added_date : "1437013195",
        tags       : ["tag1", "tag2"]
    },
    //1 - same as 0 but the added_date is different and the name is different, an additional tag3 is present
    {
        name       : "Name 2",
        identifier : "string0001",
        added_date : "1437082145",
        tags       : ["tag1", "tag3"]
    },
    //3 - a second unique element but it uses the same tags as 0
    {
        name       : "Name 3",
        identifier : "string0002",
        added_date : "1358426363",
        tags       : ["tag1", "tag2"]
    },
    //4 - third unique element with a new tag tag4
    {
        name       : "Name 4",
        identifier : "string0003",
        added_date : "1422912783",
        tags       : ["tag1", "tag4"]
    },
    // 5 - same element as 4, it was added before 4, it's tagged less than 4
    {
        name       : "Name 4",
        identifier : "string0003",
        added_date : "1358426363",
        tags       : ["tag1"]
    }
]
```

The unique identifier here is the property `identifier` and don't care about the name being different. In the case of element `0` and `1` I would expect one `:Element` node in the database.

**I will have two nodes:**

- `Element` that holds the `name`, `identifier` and `added_date`
- `Tag` that has the name of the tag
- My relationship is: `Element`s are `TAGGED_WITH` the `Tag`

My horrible little script below so far creates a query that consists of 3 queries that first create the `Element`, then the `Tag`, and then relates `Element` to `Tag` and executes it.

**What my script doesn't do is:**

- `MERGE` the `Element` using only the identifier, it uses all three properties `name`, `identifier` and `added_date`.
- It doesn't record if the same identifier had multiple names (for example element `0` and `1` have two different names and could have stored an array of names: `{name: "Name 2", identifier:"string0001", added_date:"1437013195", all_names:["Name 1", "Name 2"]}` ). This is not that important, I will handle this when I know how to chain queries properly
- Similarly, the added_date property could have been merged as well: `{name: "Name 2", identifier:"string0001", added_date:"1437013195", all_names:["Name 1", "Name 2"], all_added_dates: ["1437013195","1437082145"]}` Again I will tackle this once I learn proper chaining.
- It doesn't catch errors in each step

**My Code is:**

```
var neo4j = require('neo4j-driver').v1;

// Create a driver instance, for the user neo4j with password neo4j.
// It should be enough to have a single driver per database per application.
var driver = neo4j.driver("bolt://localhost:7687", neo4j.auth.basic("neo4j", "123456"));

// Register a callback to know if driver creation was successful:
driver.onCompleted = function () {
    // proceed with using the driver, it was successfully instantiated
    console.log('successfully connected');
};

// Register a callback to know if driver creation failed.
// This could happen due to wrong credentials or database unavailability:
driver.onError = function (error) {
    console.log('Driver instantiation failed', error);
};

// Create a session to run Cypher statements in.
// Note: Always make sure to close sessions when you are done using them!
var session = driver.session();
//console.log(session);

var test = require('./test.json');
for ( var element in test ) {

    if (test.hasOwnProperty(element)) {
        var obj = test[element];
        var element_object = {name:'', identifier:'',add_date:''};
        var tags;
        for ( var prop in obj ) {
            if (obj.hasOwnProperty(prop)) {
                //console.log('obj.' + prop + ' = ' + obj[prop]);
                if (prop === 'tags') {
                    tags = obj[prop];
                } else {
                    element_object[prop] = obj[prop].replace(/["']/g, "\\\"");
                }
            }
        }
        console.log('gonna create this element', JSON.stringify(element_object));
        console.log('tagged by', tags);

        var q = 'MERGE (element:Element {identifier:"'+element_object.identifier+'", name:"'+element_object.name+'", add_date:"'+element_object.add_date+'"})\n';
        var q2 = '';
        var q3 = '';
        for(var i=0; i<tags.length;i++){
            q2+= 'MERGE(tag'+i+':Tag {name:"'+tags[i]+'"})\n';
            q3+= 'MERGE(element)-[:TAGGED_WITH]->(tag'+i+')\n';
        }
        q += q2;
        q += q3;
        q += ";";



        console.log('query:', q);


        session
            .run(q)
            .then( function(result) {
                console.log('added element:',result);
                driver.close();
            })
            .catch( function(error) {
                console.log(error);
                // Close the driver when application exits
                driver.close();
            })

    }
}
```

**What I want to write for my query run is a chain of promises that correspond to this algorithm:**

- Is there an element already with identifier `string0001`?
- If not create that; if yes, then use that (here I might write those enhancements to log all the other `added_date` and `name` properties). Now I have a reference to that `element`
- Is there a tag created with the name `tag1`? Create or return the tag. Now I have a reference to that `tag`
- Make a relationship between `element` and `tag` if the relationship doesn't exist already.

**Results expected:**

The result of this in the database can be visualized as the following if the result was in JavaScript array format:

```
 [

    {
        name       : "Name 2", //took the latest name on the list order, notice it is not Name 1 anymore
        identifier : "string0001",
        added_date : "1437082145", //took the latest added_date on the list order
        tags       : ["tag1", "tag2", "tag3"]
    },
    {
        name       : "Name 3",
        identifier : "string0002",
        added_date : "1358426363",
        tags       : ["tag1", "tag2"]
    },
    {
        name       : "Name 4",
        identifier : "string0003",
        added_date : "1358426363", //notice that the element 4 was added later than this element 5 but we took the
                                   // older date because this was merged last. in other words it was the latest element
                                   // with "string0003" in the list.
        tags       : ["tag1", "tag4"]
    }
]
```

After I would make the enhancements to support all names and all add dates then it might look like this:

```
[
    {
        name                      : "Name 2", //took the newest name in terms of added_date
        identifier                : "string0001",
        added_date                : "1437082145", //took the greatest added_date
        all_added_dates_and_names : [{'1437013195' : 'Name 1', '1437082145' : 'Name 2'}],
        tags                      : ["tag1", "tag2", "tag3"]
    },
    {
        name       : "Name 3",
        identifier : "string0002",
        added_date : "1358426363",
        tags       : ["tag1", "tag2"]
    },
    {
        name                      : "Name 4",
        identifier                : "string0003",
        added_date                : "1422912783", //took the greatest added_date
        all_added_dates_and_names : [{'1422912783' : 'Name 4', '1358426363' : 'Name 4'}],
        tags                      : ["tag1", "tag4"]
    }

]
```

I've been looking at these to figure out the best practices:

- https://github.com/sebinsua/neo4j-simple (let me know if this is any good or if there are better ones out there)
- https://neo4j.com/developer/javascript/
- https://neo4j.com/docs/api/javascript-driver/current/ I confused myself a lot here
- http://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/current/drivers/
- [How to do nested queries in neo4j](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33213191/how-to-do-nested-queries-in-neo4j) looked here for query

My expectation is similar to the example on https://neo4j.com/developer/javascript/ :

```
var neo4j = require('neo4j-driver').v1;

var driver = neo4j.driver("bolt://localhost:7687", neo4j.auth.basic("neo4j", "neo4j"));
var session = driver.session();
session
  .run( "CREATE (a:Person {name: {name}, title: {title}})", {name: "Arthur", title: "King"})
  .then( function()
  {
    return session.run( "MATCH (a:Person) WHERE a.name = {name} RETURN a.name AS name, a.title AS title",
        {name: "Arthur"})
  })
  .then( function( result ) {
    console.log( result.records[0].get("title") + " " + result.records[0].get("name") );
    session.close();
    driver.close();
  });
```

But I would like it to catch errors in each step and add would like to parameterize in my for loop.

Answer (score 1):

There are a few complications that will requires some changes.

The first is your iterative approach. This usually isn't performant with Cypher, and it's not recommended to use string concatenation to construct your queries either. Instead, I'd recommend parameterizing your input collection, and using UNWIND within the query to unwind the collection to rows, so your entire JSON gets processed all at once.

The second complication is your all_added_dates_and_names property. Neo4j does not currently allow for map type properties, nor for collections of map type properties. Your remaining options are to turn your map into a string, or to turn each added name into a connected node with an additional date property.

You'll also need [APOC Procedures](https://neo4j-contrib.github.io/neo4j-apoc-procedures/) to make it as easy as possible to construct your query, as you'll need to make use of collection union functions.

Here's a query that should work, though you'll want to replace the `with ... as json` with reference to your passed in json param , `unwind $json as row`.

```
with [
    {
        name       : "Name 1",
        identifier : "string0001",
        added_date : "1437013195",
        tags       : ["tag1", "tag2"]
    },
    {
        name       : "Name 2",
        identifier : "string0001",
        added_date : "1437082145",
        tags       : ["tag1", "tag3"]
    },
    {
        name       : "Name 3",
        identifier : "string0002",
        added_date : "1358426363",
        tags       : ["tag1", "tag2"]
    },
    {
        name       : "Name 4",
        identifier : "string0003",
        added_date : "1422912783",
        tags       : ["tag1", "tag4"]
    },
    {
        name       : "Name 4",
        identifier : "string0003",
        added_date : "1358426363",
        tags       : ["tag1"]
    }
] as json 

unwind json as row
with row.identifier as identifier, max(toInt(row.added_date)) as latestDate, 
 collect({date:toInt(row.added_date), name:row.name}) as allDatesAndNames, collect(row.tags) as allTags
// now union all collections of tags per entry with the same identifier
with identifier, latestDate, allDatesAndNames,
 reduce(tagSet = head(allTags), tags in allTags | apoc.coll.union(tagSet, tags)) as allTags
// now get the latest name corresponding with latest date
with identifier, latestDate, allDatesAndNames, allTags,
 head([entry in allDatesAndNames where entry.date = latestDate | entry.name]) as latestName
// data pre-processed, now start the merge
merge (el:Element{identifier:identifier})
set el.added_date = latestDate, el.name = latestName
foreach (entry in allDatesAndNames | 
 merge (el)-[:NAME_CHANGE]->(:NameChange{date:entry.date, name:entry.name}))
foreach (tagName in allTags | 
 merge (tag:Tag{name:tagName}) 
 merge (el)-[:TAGGED_WITH]->(tag))
```

If you need to take account for adding dates and names where a date and name in the graph is more recent than anything you're adding, you may want to just merge the :NameChange nodes (ignoring any parts of the query dealing with latestDate or latestName), and then at the end find the :NameChange node with the latest date and set the date_added and name property from that node.

Comment: If I make the `:NameChange` nodes, how can I write it using Javascript + Cypher? Although I appreciate being introduced to APOC Procedures- I do see the potentials, I am trying to lean towards the JavaScript approach. The iterative algorithm isn't a big issue for this project as it will be run few times and the data won't be huge. My priority is to become more familiar with the JS driver.